# "python (filename) build" command not working

Tags: python

I have installed cx_Freeze using the command `python -m pip install cx_Freeze --upgrade`. 
After that I set the cmd directory to the folder that contains my .py file, and I typed `python scratch.py build`, but instead of compiling my code into an exe, it simply ran my code in the command line.
How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

That's not what the `python` command does.

Python is conceptually pretty simple to use. You've explored two ways to use it so far:

- `python -m pip ...` runs the python module called `pip`, passing everything in the `...` as arguments to that script.
- `python scratch.py ...` runs the file `scratch.py`, passing everything in the `...` as arguments to that script.

What you're doing here, then, is running the script `scratch.py` with the argument `build` - which probably doesn't mean anything to the program, so it just gets ignored. The script `pip` (which actually exists as its own executable already; you can do `pip ...` without the `python -m`) has special behaviors set up for when `install` is given as an argument to it, and so on.

If you want to build an `.exe` file out of your code, you'll have to look into tools that can do that for you, such as [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) and [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/). You may find [This article](https://medium.com/dreamcatcher-its-blog/making-an-stand-alone-executable-from-a-python-script-using-pyinstaller-d1df9170e263) helpful, as it elaborates more on these tools.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried pyinstaller and it works perfectly!